# How to make a frame1 in the timeline, to be my startpage, when I already have a frame on the first timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 3 layers in the timeline, and I want to make a new layer, and then use the new layer to be my first frame (like a startpage).
How do I do that?

Comment: put everything in that startpage layer inside a startpage MovieClip...do a similar thing for the other pages, and set the `visible` property to false for all clips other than startpage.

Comment: put everything in that startpage layer. What do you mean?

Comment: inside a startpage MovieClip. I dont understand ...

Comment: nevermind...sounds more like a superuser.com question. leave your new layer(that you want to use as your first frame) in it's current location and drag the remaining layers which are not part of the startpage content to other frames. that should do it.

Comment: If I drag the remaining layers which are not part of the startpage content to other frames, the screen start shaking when I press cmd+enter.

Comment: I wonder if I could send you (George Profenza) my fla.-file, if you could add a startpage, It will help me alot to see it ready ...

Comment: just add a `stop();` action on the first frame...it's a basic command and you'll use it a lot to control the timeline. For details see in the **"Using a stop action to stop the Timeline from looping"** section in the [Creating your first document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_cs5_createfla.html) article.

Comment: I would recommend heading over to superuser.com to get the help on the basics and using stackoverflow.com for more advanced code related issues.

Comment: Thanks George, Im gonna try to add a stop(); action on the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

Flash does not support show/hide of layers. Learn about working with Movieclips. You should find a lot by just searching for it.

```
myStartClip.visible = true;
```

A "shaking screen" means you probably have compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use layers or frames (aside from the first frame where you put all your code as usual of course).
It's an AS3 exercise, which means you should be working mainly in AS3 code, and not in frames and layers.

You put the "start page" in a container, which can be a Sprite or a MovieClip.
The "start page" can contain for instance a background, a textfield with some instructions and a start button.

This means that you have to create a new container for instance

```
var startContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();  
addChild(startContainer);  // and maybe position it with x and y
```

Then you create the things you need on your start page

```
var infoTf:TextField = new TextField();
infoTf.text = "some game description and how to play";
var bg:SomeBackground = new SomeBackground();
var startBtn:SomeBtn = new SomeBtn();
startBtn.addEventListener(MouseClick.CLICK, handleMClick_startGame);
```

And then you add these things to the **container**.

```
startContainer.addChild(bg);  // add the other things too of course
```

Then when you press the startBtn, you use removeChild on the entire **container** and don't forget to remove the eventListener for the startBtn

After that you add the content for the game either directly on the stage, or to another mainContainer if you so prefer.

And in the end you use the same technique for the game over page.